# Getting bluetooth to work on Raspberry Pi 3 after a dist-upgrade

Tags: bluetooth, minibian

This is really frustrating. Not expecting a definitive answer... but I can hope ;)  Just some more troubleshooting ideas would be great. Clearly this has something to do with serial ports.  But what???  I did a dist-upgrade to get my image working with the RPi 3.  Wireless works great but bluetooth.... This is what I've done so far:

```
apt-get install pi-bluetooth bluez bluez-firmware
```

Modified /boot/config.txt to add:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

Added root user (which I'm logged in as) to bluetooth group:

```
usermod -G bluetooth -a root
```

This is the output from systemctl status hciuart.service on a WORKING RPi 3 system using the latest Raspian jessie:

```
sudo systemctl status hciuart.service
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-07-22 21:17:08 UTC; 24h ago
  Process: 450 ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 bcm43xx 921600 noflow - (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 775 (hciattach)
   CGroup: /system.slice/hciuart.service
           └─775 /usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -

Jul 22 21:17:08 pidev2lcd hciattach[450]: bcm43xx_init
Jul 22 21:17:08 pidev2lcd hciattach[450]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd
Jul 22 21:17:08 pidev2lcd hciattach[450]: Set Controller UART speed to 921600 bit/s
Jul 22 21:17:08 pidev2lcd hciattach[450]: Device setup complete
Jul 22 21:17:08 pidev2lcd systemd[1]: Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
```

This is the output from my BROKEN system:

```
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-07-23 17:33:56 EDT; 14min ago
  Process: 290 ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 bcm43xx 921600 noflow - (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 23 17:33:55 minibian hciattach[290]: Can't open serial port: No such file or directory
Jul 23 17:33:55 minibian hciattach[290]: Can't initialize device: No such file or directory
Jul 23 17:33:56 minibian systemd[1]: hciuart.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 23 17:33:56 minibian systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Jul 23 17:33:56 minibian systemd[1]: Unit hciuart.service entered failed state.
```

/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service is the same on both machines:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/proc/device-tree/soc/gpio@7e200000/bt_pins
Before=bluetooth.service
After=dev-serial1.device

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is /boot/cmdline.txt on the WORKING system:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

This is /boot/cmdline.txt on the BROKEN system:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Modifying cmdline.txt on the broken system didn't help.

Comment: You have installed so much unnecessary stuff and modified so many things you may be better to do a fresh install (which should work out of the box). The following may help [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: Sorry I don't grok that.  What is unnecessary about the packages I've installed.  Which one(s) specifically are unnecessary?  BTW I'm working with Minibian so there is no fluff at all.  I've only modified two things.  The point is to understand why it doesn't work and not just go with the blackbox approach.  That way when it breaks again which it surely will I can fix it.

Comment: AFAIK `pi-bluetooth` is the only package needed.  Dependencies should be automatically loaded. Your question implied `Raspbian` I can't say what `Minibian` needs. This was a generic response - it is almost impossible to debug when so many things change. On the latest firmware `/dev/serial1` is the default secondary UART

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few people have asked questions about `Minibian` so I decided to give it a try.

It REALLY is basic! It doesn't install `sudo` or `nano`.

The instructions on https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/ are even more basic.

The instructions for setting up WiFi and Bluetooth on the Pi3 are kind of there, but leave `/dev/ttyAMA0` connected to the console and fail to create the symlinks required by the `hciuart.service`

There needs to be `udev` rules to create the `dev/serial1` link which can be installed with `raspberrypi-sys-mods`